# How can I make the padding of this footer smaller?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

The footer looks too big and almost takes up most of the screen especially when it is for smaller devices. How can I decrease the height of this footer so it won't look too big for large and small screens.

[image]

```
import { Container, Box, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

const Footer = (props) => {
  return (
    <footer>
      <Box
        px={{ xs: 3, sm: 10 }}
        py={{ xs: 5, sm: 10 }}
        // bgcolor="text.secondary"
        // color="white"
        color="text.secondary"
        bgcolor="#E3F2FD"
      >
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
          <Grid container spacing={5}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Box borderBottom={1}>Help</Box>
              <Box>Contactt</Box>
              <Box>Support</Box>
              <Box>Privacy</Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Box borderBottom={1}>Help</Box>
              <Box>Contactt</Box>
              <Box>Support</Box>
              <Box>Privacy</Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Box borderBottom={1}>Help</Box>
              <Box>Contactt</Box>
              <Box>Support</Box>
              <Box>Privacy</Box>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          {/* change name of the website here */}
          <Box textAlign="center" pt={{ xs: 5, sm: 10 }} pb={{ xs: 5, sm: 0 }}>
            Website &reg; {new Date().getFullYear()}
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

This is the codesandbox for this footer - https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-frog-ros09?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have submitted an answer, please have a check and verify if it's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the big padding comes from the `px` and `py` props in the `Box` component.

From here https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/, we can see that `px` is horizontal padding (`padding-left` and `padding-right`) also `py` is vertical padding (`padding-top` and `padding-bottom`).

From here https://material-ui.com/customization/spacing/, we can see that the default padding for Material UI is 8 px for `spacing = 1`.

From here https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/, we can see taht `xs` is extra small screen and `sm` is small screen.

So, `px={{ xs: 3, sm: 10 }}` means that the padding left and right are both 3 * 8 px = 24 px for extra small screen and padding left and right are both 10 * 8 px = 80 px for small screen or above (because no `md`, `lg`, and `xl` are defined in the code).

Here is the screenshot if you comment the `px` and `py` props in the `Box` component.

```js
  return (
      <Box
        // px={{ xs: 3, sm: 10 }}
        // py={{ xs: 5, sm: 10 }}
        // bgcolor="text.secondary"
        // color="white"
        color="text.secondary"
        bgcolor="#E3F2FD"
      >
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Box borderBottom={1}>Help</Box>
              <Box>Contactt</Box>
              <Box>Support</Box>
              <Box>Privacy</Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Box borderBottom={1}>Help</Box>
              <Box>Contactt</Box>
              <Box>Support</Box>
              <Box>Privacy</Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Box borderBottom={1}>Help</Box>
              <Box>Contactt</Box>
              <Box>Support</Box>
              <Box>Privacy</Box>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          {/* change name of the website here */}
          <Box textAlign="center" pt={{ xs: 5, sm: 10 }} pb={{ xs: 5, sm: 0 }}>
            Website &reg; {new Date().getFullYear()}
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </Box>
  )
```

[image]